# Get last row value from PHP ADODB MySQL loop

Tags: php, mysql, adodb

I am trying to get the last row value from my select query.

This is my PHP query using ADODB:

```
$con->Execute("SET @depos=0");
$con->Execute("SET @total=$openingbalance");
$sql = "SELECT if( credit >0, @depos := credit , @depos := @depos + credit - debit ) AS depos_bal, @total := @total + `credit` - `debit` AS net_bal FROM `table` WHERE `mydate` < '".$monthstarts."' ORDER BY `mydate` ASC, `credit` DESC";
    $ssresults=$con->Execute($sql);
    $fnew = $ssresults->getrows();

    for($i=0;$i<count($fnew);$i++)
    {
        $bal = $fnew[$i]['net_bal'];
    }
 echo $bal;
```

Here I want to fetch the last row value from the loop.

For example:

```
 Balance
 ----------
 150.00
 250.00
 350.00
 600.00
 850.52 <----- this is the row I want to fetch from the query.
```

How can I fetch this? Kindly help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of for loop try this:-

```
$fnew = $ssresults->getrows();

$bal = $fnew[count($fnew)-1]['net_bal'];

 echo $bal;
```

note:- `count` give total number of element present in array. and array index start from `0` so `count($fnew)-1` give you last record. thanks.

Comment: what is coint? you mean count?

Comment: yeah, not getting the desired result... net_bal summing up with all rows

Comment: What amount is it returning then?

Comment: Since am adding and subtracting from the credit and debit, I should loop to get the desired result

Comment: working on it please.. give me sometime, am also trying with something else. will update the same in sometime

Comment: Your solution perfectly worked, I was making a wrong query with where clause. Appreciate your time and efforts in helping me. I am too thankful and you saved my 2 hours frustration. Thank you... Accepted and upvoted.